# Is there a general way to convert ROS messages into JSON format?

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to convert arbitrary ROS messages into JSON format.  Is there an official way of doing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196365/is-there-a-general-way-to-convert-ros-messages-into-json-format?/) by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosbridge provides you a JSON API to ROS

http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2020-06-24**:
Is there a way to just run rosbridge_library (to just get ROS messages to JSON conversion)?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know much about this topic, but you might be able to find something useful in the newly announced [mongodb_log](http://wiki.ros.org/mongodb_log) package, I believe MongoDB uses JSON, and I think in that package they do automated conversions from ROS messages to JSON.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just tried the [rospy_message_converter](https://github.com/baalexander/rospy_message_converter).

Works really well! :)

---

Originally posted by [Falko](https://answers.ros.org/users/23523/falko/) with karma: 268 on 2015-11-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosbridge is probably the better answer, but just in case, here's a method that will at least work on messages whose content can be rendered as a string with the python `str()` function.

```
import json
import yaml

def msg2json(msg):
   ''' Convert a ROS message to JSON format'''
   y = yaml.load(str(msg))
   return json.dumps(y,indent=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
    P = PoseStamped()
    print msg2json(P)
```

---

```
{
    "header": {
        "stamp": {
            "secs": 0, 
            "nsecs": 0
        }, 
        "frame_id": "", 
        "seq": 0
    }, 
    "pose": {
        "position": {
            "y": 0.0, 
            "x": 0.0, 
            "z": 0.0
        }, 
        "orientation": {
            "y": 0.0, 
            "x": 0.0, 
            "z": 0.0, 
            "w": 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) with karma: 242 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on 2022-04-06**:
Hi,
The above solution was helpful thanks for that. I have another question about how do you revert it back to ros msg.